# How truncate the ../ characters from string in bash?

Tags: bash

How can I truncate the ../ or .. characters from string in bash
So, If I have strings

```
str1=../lib
str2=/home/user/../dir1/../dir2/../dir3
```

then how I can get string without any .. characters  in a string like after truncated result should be

```
str1=lib
str2=/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Please note that I am not interesting in absolute path of string.

Comment: If you don't want to normalize the path, then what should `a/.../b` become? keep the segment or change to `a/.b`? or `a/./b`? How about `a/b..c`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit ? A file ? A script ? Your environment ? user input ?

Comment: You realize that "/home/user/../dir1/../dir2/../dir3" and "/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3" are two *completely* different paths, right?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, yes I realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
pax> str3=$(echo $str2 | sed 's?\.\./??g') ; echo $str3
/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Just be aware (as you seem to be) that's a *different* path to the one you started with.

If you're going to be doing this infrequently, forking an external process to do it is fine. If you want to use it *many* times per second, such as in a tight loop, the internal `bash` commands will be quicker:

```
pax> str3=${str2//..\/} ; echo $str3
/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

This uses `bash` pattern substitution as described in the man page (modified slightly to adapt to the question at hand):

> **`${parameter/pattern/string}`**
>
> The `parameter` is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against its value is replaced with `string`. If pattern  begins with `/`, *all* matches of pattern are replaced with string.
>
> If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the `/` following `pattern` may be omitted.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` in the parameter expansion, as the argument to the `//` operator is a shell pattern, not a regular expression. In a pattern, `.` has no special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to fork a sub-shell to call `sed`. Use `bash` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
echo ${var//..\/}
```

```
str1=../lib
str2=/home/user/../dir1/../dir2/../dir3
```

```
echo ${str1//..\/}     # Outputs lib
echo ${str2//..\/}     # Outputs /home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Comment: Simple string manipulations can be done using the bash features instead of forking a external command , sed is destined for complex pattern matching and editing of a stream

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.`, as the argument to the `//` operator is a shell pattern, not a regular expression. In a pattern, `.` has no special meaning.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Have updated the answer to reflect your suggestion. Whenever you get a chance, can you please provide a doc location which explains that behavior?

Comment: From the (4.1) man page documentation for the operator: "Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion".

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Honestly I was completely unaware that the two were different. I had read that line but thought pattern and regex were same. I found more about the shell patterns [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to achieve it

```
sed 's/\.\.\///g'
```

For example

```
echo $str2 | sed 's/\.\.\///g'

OP => /home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3
```